# Как создать json файл при помощи Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Имеется программа которая формирует определенные данные. Но я застрял на этапе, когда данные сформировались, а я не могу их записать в файл, если его не существует в директории со скриптом.

Вот часть кода функции:

```
filename = input('Pls, enter a filename: ')
with open(filename, 'r+') as f_obj:
    json.dump(pswd, f_obj)
f_obj.close()
```

Если в папке не существует файла, который указан в `filename` программа останвливается. Могу ли я реализовать похожую функцию, только чтобы она создавала в директории файл с указаным названием?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Если нужно просто создать новый или перезаписать старый файл - используйте режим открытия файла `'w'`.
- Если нужно дописать данные в файл, не затирая старые - используйте режим `'a'`. Если файл не существует, он будет создан.

[Документация по функции `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите хэлп по режиму открытия файлов `'+'` всегда проверяет, что файл уже есть, иначе ошибка.

Comment: тоесть, без проверки он никак не создается? 
какой тогда можно использовать аналог, не подскажете?

Comment: ну я очень советую хэлп посмотреть, тем более эти режимы открытия файлов и в C++, и еще, наверное, во многих местах... при режиме `w` будет создан новый файл, например.